# I have one input and I want button clicks to cause the input to get focus

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one input with one icon. I want:

1. when I click on the icon for the input to get focus
2. when I click on the icon for the input to get focusout

For number one I wrote this code and for number two I don't know what to do

```
$(".top-search i").click(function(){
    document.getElementById("input-search").focus();
});

<div class="top-search">
    <form>
        <input id="input-search" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Type + Enter"/>
        <i class="ion-ios-search"></i>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: consider using a `label` for something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: Now I know what you mean, working version:

```js
let hasFocus = false; /* set state variable */
$(".top-search i").click(function() {
    const setState = hasFocus ? 'blur' : 'focus';
    $('#input-search')[setState]();
    hasFocus = !hasFocus; /* reverse current state */
});
```

```css
.ion-ios-search {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="top-search">
    <form>
        <input id="input-search" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Type + Enter" />
        <i class="ion-ios-search">Click Me</i>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: @mortezaYung Updated answer, I understand what you need now

Answer (score 0):

You can use blur in order to un-focus your input.
Something like this:

```
$(".top-search i").click(function(){
   $("#input-search").blur();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".top-search i:focus").click(function(){
    document.getElementById("input-search").blur();
});
```

Comment: An explanation would be nice rather than just code answers